# Wide-characters support on VxWorks downloadable kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, vxworks, wchar, widechar

I'm working on porting a project from Linux to VxWorks DKM. 
But I face a problem: On linux, wide characters and wide char functions ( like wcslen() or mbrtowc() ) are used in some parts of this project and since VxWorks DKM doesn't support wide chars ( and wide chars functions...) i'm stuck.
My question is : Is there any alternative to Wide chars on VxWorks DKM I can use ?

Wide char are suported in the RTP mode of VxWorks but not in DKM.

Comment: Can you use RTP instead of DKM? I am assuming you have solved the issue now, perhaps you could provide your solution as an answer to this question?